# Javascript soft lock window on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am using Vue for my frontend and I have an intro section that has a v-if statement to show only if on home route, then a content section. In the content section there is a navbar with the sticky attribute.

I don't really like how the website behaves at the moment because the sticky navbar will easily get out of alignment and cover the content when I scroll to the "top" of the home page (below the intro).

I would therefore like to have some sort of soft lock to align it properly, and if the user scrolls multiple times up or down it will unlock.

I guess it has to do with eventlisteners on scroll but I'm unsure how to unlock it. I'm guessing it has to do with a delay, and if the user scrolls again after that delay it unlocks, or a scroll count but that may not feel as smooth.

(I tried CSS scroll snap but I can't get it to work)

```
<template>
<section id="home">
  <section v-if="this.$route.path=='/'" id="intro">
    <div class="intro__content">
        intro content
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div v-if="displayCart" class="shopping-cart__wrapper" :style='{ left: cartLeftDistance + "px"}'>
          shopping cart
        </div>
        <nav class="nav__main-nav">
            navigation
        </nav>
        <router-view/>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="footer">
      footer code
  </section>
</section>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
#intro {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav__main-nav {
  z-index: 100;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.shopping-cart__wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 6em;
  width: 380px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? No idea what you are trying to achieve and how your page looks like, I can't suggest the right solution.

Comment: @Cheetha I edited the post to have the important code displayed
[Screenshot of the issue](https://imgur.com/q7nG4zS)
My problem is when a user scrolls up on the home page I would like  the scrolling to softly lock the window position so it doesn't show the intro section, and doesn't cover the website content below navigation unless the user scrolls multiple times